# dropdownlist solo refresca la primera vez aun teniendo el selectedindexchange y postback true

Tags: asp.net

Tengo un `dropdownlist` que tiene un evento `ddltiempo_SelectedIndexChanged` el cual tiene que actualizar un `gridview` cada vez que cambie hace una consulta   a la bd, pero solo lo hace la primera vez
(el dropdownlist ya tiene autopostback true)

Este es el codigo

```
protected void ddltiempo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            if (valortiempo!= 0)
            {
                tiempo= dc.Ex_Consultamonto(valortiempo);
            }
       gvcalendario.DataSource = tiempo.List();
       gvcalendario.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que el flujo es el siguiente:

Cambias el valor del dropdown > hace postback > no carga el gridview.

Cuando hace el postback quizás no tienes tratado que haga algo en el Page_Load.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Si no es postback, primer inicio de la pagina
        }
        else
        {
            // Cuando es postback recoges el valor

            if (valortiempo != 0)
            {
                tiempo = dc.Ex_Consultamonto(valortiempo);
            }
            gvcalendario.DataSource = tiempo.List();
            gvcalendario.DataBind();
        }

    }
```